# Missing param for for named route after successful api call

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router

I have a Settings component where a user can update their informations, after the update is successful I get in the console missing param for named route and all the inputs that should contain user data are empty, and when I try accessing the settings page it redirects to the home page even though all the data needed for it to work is still in the component's data.
This is the component's method to that commits an action in vuex store

```
    updateUser(){
            const fd = new FormData()
            //check if avatar is of type file
            if ('File' in window && this.avatar instanceof File){
                fd.append('avatar', this.avatar, this.avatar.name)
            }
            fd.append('_method', 'PUT')
            fd.append('city_id', this.userData? this.userData.city.id:this.city)
            fd.append('oldPassword', this.oldPassword)
            fd.append('newPassword', this.newPassword)

            this.$store.dispatch('User/update', fd)
                .then(() =>{
                  this.success = this.user.user.message
                }).catch(err => {
                this.error = err.response.data.message
            })
        }
```

the above method triggers this vuex action

```
    update({commit}, user){
    return axios.post(`/api/${user.name}/update`, user)
        .then(( {data} ) => {
            commit('UPDATE_USER_DATA', data)
        })
}
```

And here's the UPDATE_USER_DATA mutation

```
    UPDATE_USER_DATA(state, userData){
    let user = localStorage.getItem('user')
    const data = JSON.parse(user)
    state.user.user = userData
    data['user'] = userData
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

This is the laravel method that's called

```
    public function update(User $user, Request $request)
{
    $attributes = [];
    if(request('city_id') && $request['city_id'] !== null){
        $attributes['city_id'] = $request['city_id'];
    }
    if (request('oldPassword') &&  Hash::check($request['oldPassword'], auth()->user()->getAuthPassword())
    ){
        if(request('newPassword')) {
            $attributes['password'] = Hash::make($request['newPassword']);
        }
    } else{
        return response()->json([
            'message' => "L'ancien mot de passe est incorrecte.",
            'user' => $user
        ], 400);
    }

    if (request('avatar')) {
        $attributes['avatar'] = request('avatar')->store('avatars');
    }

    // This is where I have the issue
    if (!empty($attributes)){
        if($user->update($attributes)){
            return response()->json([
            'user' => $user,
            'message' => 'Votre compte a été modifié avec succés'
            ], 200);
        }
    }

    return response()->json([
        'message' => "Votre compte n'a pas été modifié, réessayez plus tard",
        'user' => $user
    ], 400);
}
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code to the question itself. Without code, difficult to suggest a fix.

Comment: Providing more detailed code in formatted text-format.

Comment: This is an Laravel error and you only shown front end code, which is not at all related to this error :)

Comment: @mrhn I updated the post to contain the code, please check again and let me know if you could find what's causing the issue

Comment: In your error what line does your code fail on?

Comment: @mrhn when it sends back a 400 status code everything is good on the frontend, but when it sends back a 200 status code I immediately get on the console missing param for named route settings, expecting user to be defined, and if I refresh the page the settings form is empty and even the url is just 127.0.0.1:8000 instead of 127.0.0.1:8000/:user/settings